# html page ends half and doesn't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, overflow

I am new to html and css trying to build a reporting page directing to display different script output. unfortunately my page display only half with a scroller but I want the output to display in the main page without scroller. It would be great if someone can suggest what is wrong or missing.

```
* {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
}

html {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #555;
        font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 13px;
        overflow-y: visible;
}


table { border-collapse: collapse; } td { font-family:Verdana; font-size:11; vertical-align:center; } th { height:7px;font-family:Verdana; font-si
ze:11; font-style:bold; background-color:#81DAF5 }


.firstsec {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        overflow-y: visible;
        max-width: 1140px;
        background-size: 650px;
        background-image: url(Backup_logo.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        height: 20vh;
}

.toptext  {
        border: 0;
        background-color: #5E10B1;
        color: white;
        width: 25%;
        height: 20vh;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
}

.logo {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 22%;
        height: 40px;
        float: left;
}

.section {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 1140px;
        overflow-y: visible;
        top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved after updating the closing tag  in my html page.